# how to deny adsbygoogle script to NOT load in site using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have an issue with a bot that hacked my website and injected google ads script.
i have tried to find in the files where the script is located but i had no luck.

i been told to try block the script using .htaccess file, i have read online and tried to make my own code to block the script but no luck again.

this is what i have tried so far :

```
<Files adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-4262160458050412>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>

<Limit GET> 
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
deny from https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-4262160458050412
deny from https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js
</Limit>
```

that is how the script that the bot injected looks like :

```
<script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-4262160458050412" crossorigin="anonymous" data-checked-head="true"></script>
```

can anyone let me know why the script is still loading in my website?

Comment: But `googlesyndication.com` is an external domain, not under your control - the request is not sent to your server, so you can't block it. The only way to "BLOCK the script" is to remove the `<script>` from the HTML source.

Comment: so there is no way to block an external domain from .htaccess ?

Comment: If you know your site has been compromised and code has been altered then the first thing you have to do is TAKE THE SITE DOWN NOW. Then you have all time in the world to analyze and clean up. But wild kamikaze attempts like what you try here will not solve the problem you have.

Comment: The issue here, as so often is, that many people use systems these days that insist on the application itself being able to modify it's own code, to write it's own files. That is the cause of all those successful attacks. An application being granted to modify it's own implementation is an open invitation to everyone to come in and do whatever they want on your site. An absolute security nightmare as every admin on earth will confirm. The only real solution: the application must never be able to modify it's own code or configuration. Period.